# I am not able to resolve 'lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression' error on a legal XPATH expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I am trying to parse an xpath but it is giving Invalid expression error.

The code that should work:

```
x = tree.xpath("//description/caution[1]/preceding-sibling::*/name()!='warning'")
print(x)
```

Expected result is a boolean value but it is showing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poc_xpath2.0_v1.py", line 9, in <module>
    x = tree.xpath("//description/caution[1]/preceding-sibling::*/name()!='warning'")
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 2276, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 359, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

Comment: First, what version of xpath are you using? Second, it would be helpful to have the xml code you're working with.

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is because `name()` isn't a valid node type. Your XPath would only be valid as XPath 2.0 or greater. [lxml only supports XPath 1.0](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html).

You would need to move the `name() != 'warning'` into a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates).

Also, if you want a True/False result, wrap the xpath in [`boolean()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-boolean)...

```py
tree.xpath("boolean(//description/caution[1]/preceding-sibling::*[name()!='warning'])")
```

Full example...

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<doc>
    <description>
        <warning></warning>
        <caution></caution>
    </description>
</doc>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

x = tree.xpath("boolean(//description/caution[1]/preceding-sibling::*[name()!='warning'])")
print(x)
```

This would print `False`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It is working just fine. Thanks again